# How to send table value with form, radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

Example

Html code in Table

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='example 1' name='text1' /></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' value='example 1' name='radio1' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='example 2' name='text2' /></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' value='example 2' name='radio2' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='example 3' name='text3' /></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' value='example 3' name='radio3' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to send clicked value when if radio button clicked

button

1 clicked -> send radio 1 value

2 clicked -> send radio 2 value

3 clicked -> sens radio 3 value

So question

How to send table value with form, radio button?

Comment: That, for your info, **is an invalid HTML**. There's not even a single `=` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript. Just "listen" to the `click` event for each input.

You can send it to the server using [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', function(elm) {
    console.log(input.value);
    // Send this value to the server with ajax or something
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='example 1' name='text1' /></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' value='example 1' name='radio1' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='example 2' name='text2' /></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' value='example 2' name='radio2' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='example 3' name='text3' /></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' value='example 3' name='radio3' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also I think all radio buttons need to have same name.

Comment: @user2181397 You are right asswome that all the radios is in the same group, which I'm not sure. I just followed his code.

Answer (score 0):

you can send data with the help of code something like this. you can write the code for sending the data using XMLHttpRequest in the sendValue function.

```js
var sendValue = function()
{
  alert(this.value);  
}

var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   
for (var i=0;i<inputTags.length;i++){
     if(inputTags[i].type == "radio")
     {
     inputTags[i].addEventListener("click", sendValue);
     }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='example 1' name='text1' /></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' value='example 1' name='radio1' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='example 2' name='text2' /></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' value='example 2' name='radio2' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='text' value='example 3' name='text3' /></td>
    <td> <input type='radio' value='example 3' name='radio3' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```